# Найти наибольшую высоту треугольника

Tags: python

Найти наибольшую высоту треугольника который задан длиной его сторон и проверить его существование, если можно с объяснениями

```
A = int(input("Введите A - "))
B = int(input("Введите B - "))
C = int(input("Введите C - "))
if A + B > C and A + C > B and B + C > A:
    print("Треугольник существует")
else:
    print("Треугольник не существует")

P = (A + B + C) / 2
print(P)
```

если я правильно понимаю - сначала нужно вычислить стороны треугольника, а  потом уже среди них найти самое  большое  число?

Comment: Сначала лучше проверить, что треугольник существует, потому что могут быть заданы длины сторон, не соответствующие правилу "любая сторона треугольника меньше суммы двух других сторон" и только потом пытаться [искать высоты](https://www.fxyz.ru/формулы_по_геометрии/плоские_фигуры/треугольник/высота_треугольника/) и максимальную среди них.

Comment: Формула Герона. Потом считаешь высоту на наименьшую сторону.

Comment: @nonForgivingJesus,  
так?
A = int(input("Введите A - "))
B = int(input("Введите B - "))
C = int(input("Введите C - "))
if A + B > C and A + C > B and B + C > A:
 print("Треугольник существует")
else:
 print("Треугольник не существует")

P = (A + B + C) / 2
print(P)

Comment: поправила вверху ^

Comment: большая высота строится от меньшей стороны

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поправил ваш код из комментариев:

```
# Функция выбирает наибольшее из чисел
def greater_of_three(num1, num2, num3):
    if (num1 > num2) and (num1 > num3):
        largest = num1
    elif (num2 > num1) and (num2 > num3):
        largest = num2
    else:
        largest = num3
    return largest

def height(side1, side2, side3, perimeter):
    p = perimeter/2
    # формула вычисляет высоту, опущенную на side1
    return 2*((p*(p-side1)*(p-side2)*(p-side3))**(0.5))/side1 

A = float(input("Введите A - ")) 
B = float(input("Введите B - ")) 
C = float(input("Введите C - ")) 
if A + B > C and A + C > B and B + C > A: 
    print("Треугольник существует") 
    p = (A + B + C) 
    h1 = height(A, B, C, p)
    h2 = height(B, C, A, p)
    h3 = height(C, B, A, p)
    print(greater_of_three(h1, h2, h3))
else: 
    print("Треугольник не существует")
```

Здесь в `h1`,`h2`,`h3` помещается вычисленная высота по данной формуле:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А потом вызывается функция, ищущая наибольшее число из трех

Comment: спасибо большое!